# How to implement the dot(.) symbol when implementating regular expression parser?

Tags: regex

I'm implementing a regular expression parser by using algorithms in the dragon book. Now I can generate a DTran table and parse some basic regular expressions like: `(a|b)*abb`.

But I encountered a problem when implementing the `.` symbol, which matches any character. There is no text about it in the dragon book, is there some examples or articles about implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it yourself, that is the fun of it.  Below is not much an answer, but nevertheless.

1. Track the state/condition of a match for n number "." so .[n]  and then continue pattern matching.
2. Cheat and look ahead, not really a good idea.  The since .[n] could be large, but likely not.

It is really rather similar to other pattern matching, like *, and remember multiple matches could occur on the same text; which is why maybe the left it out (A Dtran or state machine gets hard when the grammar is rich); plus it is really similar, but accepts an char.  Heck you might have to switch to an NFA  (nondeterministic finite automaton) to keep it simple.

Clearly I have not worked through the dragon book, but covered it in college, "The theory of computation".  I drew many state machines.